# How to store a 3d array of strings using Shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Flutter and doing something like a calendar where all user-created Events are stored in a 3d array `IventList[month][day][numOfIvent]`. I am trying to encode the array into a string in order to save it through Shared preferences, and then decode it back when receiving data using the `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` methods.
But when decoding the resulting array, I get `error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [buzhigsr_app] lib \ calender.dart: 35)`. Maybe someone knows how to solve this error or otherwise save the array through Shared preferences? Thanks in advance to everyone.

```
  List tList = List.generate(12, (m) => List.generate(31, (d) => List.generate(40, (i) => "")));
  getAndSendData() async{
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('key', jsonEncode(tList));
  tList = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('key'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of prefs.setString('key', jsonEncode(tList)) is String?. jsonDecode() takes String as an argument, so it raises an error when you give it String?. You just have to do this to check that it's not null.

```
List<List<List<String>>> tList = List.generate(
        12, (m) => List.generate(31, (d) => List.generate(40, (i) => "")));
    getAndSendData() async {
      var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString('key', jsonEncode(tList));
      final listString = prefs.getString('key');
  

      if (listString != null) {
        final decodedList = jsonDecode(listString);
        if (listString != null) {
      final decodedList = jsonDecode(listString);
      final decodedTList = (decodedList as List)
          .map((firstD) => (firstD as List)
              .map((secondD) =>
                  (secondD as List).map((thirdD) => thirdD.toString()).toList())
              .toList())
          .toList();
      tList = decodedTList;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem is solved, but I came up with a different one. When decoding the string, the assignment fails and an error pops up: E / flutter (6216): [ERROR: flutter / lib / ui / ui_dart_state.cc (199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List <dynamic>' is not a subtype of type ' List <List <List <String> >> '

Comment: Oh yeah, flutter is not sure that jsonDecode output is a 3d list. You have to assign jsonDecode(listString) to some new variable and check if that variable is a 3D list. The. You can assign it to tList.

Comment: The problem is that when I check jsonDecode (listString), or a new variable that I passed the jsonDecode (listString) value to, using .runtimeType I get it as List <dynamic> data type. Does this mean that after encoding the array, its type has changed, or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I mean tat by checking Flutter think that decodedList is a List<dynamic>

Comment: Yes, you're right, jsonDecode does not deserialise nested arrays (or objects).
I fixed the answer to deserialise by hand.
A better way to do this would be to make your 3d array into a model and use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or similar to serialise and deserialise.